# VLC enable matroska subtitles by default

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles, matroska

I have some movies in [matroska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) format. They have english subtitles in. The problem is I have to manually select those by either clicking `V` or selecting them from the context menu.

Now I've seen those threads:

[How can I make VLC auto-select subtitles in an MKV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/836592/how-can-i-make-vlc-auto-select-subtitles-in-an-mkv-file)

[Can VLC be set to enable subtitles by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/1283817/can-vlc-be-set-to-enable-subtitles-by-default)

The first one suggests that I should set the `Subtitle track ID` option in VLC to match the subtitle track id from my movie. Fair enough, it works, but when I launch a different one - it doesn't.

The second one suggests using `-1` for `Subtitle track` and `Subtitle track ID` and selecting `English` as a preferred language. Now, this is better as it works for most kind of files, but there is one problem: What if the subtitles are not named as `English` (i.e. they are just `Sub track 1`)? Well, then it doesn't work.

So my question here would be: Is there a way to modify those files (i.e. with `mkvmerge`), and by modifying I mean just changing the subtitles name (or language name - don't know how it works in `matroska`)? And if not - can I somehow make it work in VLC then?

Comment: I can't make it **not** play by default, for me it always plays the first subs track if the languages aren't specified. Try a settings wipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) You can change your settings in VLC by going to Tools > Preferences > Subtitles/OSD and set Preferred Subtitle Language as **eng**. It will make English subtitles as default.

2) You can use mkvpropedit in order to set all the English subtiltes as forced:

```
mkvpropedit video.mkv --edit track:s1 --set forced-track=1
```

For batch processing your files in the same folder, open a command line and type on Windows:

```
FOR %G IN (*.mkv) DO (mkvpropedit.exe "%~nG.mkv" --edit track:s1 --set forced-track=1)
```